# How do you effectively solve node module issues when google isn't providing many answers?

Tags: sass, node-modules, sass-loader, resolve-url-loader

I received this issue and google isn't providing many case-specific examples to work from. Can anyone decode this? I am not really sure what the main issue is.

[image]

I have followed the file path of the first issue to cjs.js file but there isn't much there

```
"use strict";

const loader = require("./index");

module.exports = loader.default;
```

And the file path of the second issue leads me to this

```
var correctedContent = params.removeCR && (os.EOL !== '\\r') ?
sourceContent.replace(ORPHAN_CR_REGEX, ' $1') :
sourceContent;
```

[Github link](https://github.com/BryanMF87/scumm-bar-brawl) for context.

Comment: first thing i would try is commenting out the "use strict" and create a simple, simple print hello script run it (tell us whether prbl is with modules install in google platform or your code). Provide the code you're written.

Comment: @MZM Use strict was removed from index.js and I added the Github link for context

Comment: Looks like the error is due to version incompatibility, determine the versions used by google for css_loader and webpack and match that in your dependencies file, see this link  https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/1243